# grep particular details from a file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to grep particular details from a file and save that to another file.

Here is the file contents :

---

> `Name                                       : abc`
>
> `CollationName                              : xxxxxxxxx`
>
> `Edition                                    : System`
>
> `MaxSizeGB                                  : 5`
>
> `MaxSizeBytes                               : 5368709120`
>
> `ServiceObjectiveName                       : System`
>
> `ServiceObjectiveAssignmentStateDescription : Complete`
>
> `CreationDate                               : 02-Jul-14 4:14:19 AM`
>
> `RecoveryPeriodStartDate                    : 02-Jul-14 4:14:19 AM`
>
> `Name                                       : def`
>
> `CollationName                              : xxxxxxxxxxxxx`
>
> `Edition                                    : Standard`
>
> `MaxSizeGB                                  : 250`
>
> `MaxSizeBytes                               : 268435456000`
>
> `ServiceObjectiveName                       : S2`
>
> `ServiceObjectiveAssignmentStateDescription : Complete`
>
> `CreationDate                               : 25-Jan-15 6:39:41 PM`
>
> `RecoveryPeriodStartDate                    : 01-Mar-15 3:00:00 AM`
>
> `Name                                       : ghi`
>
> `CollationName                              : xxxxxxxx`
>
> `Edition                                    : Standard`
>
> `MaxSizeGB                                  : 250`
>
> `MaxSizeBytes                               : 268435456000`
>
> `ServiceObjectiveName                       : S2`
>
> `ServiceObjectiveAssignmentStateDescription : Complete`
>
> `CreationDate                               : 25-Jan-15 3:19:01 PM`
>
> `RecoveryPeriodStartDate                    : 01-Mar-15 3:00:00 AM`
>
> `Name                                       : hjiyt`
>
> `CollationName                              : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
>
> `Edition                                    : Standard`
>
> `MaxSizeGB                                  : 250`
>
> `MaxSizeBytes                               : 268435456000`
>
> `ServiceObjectiveName                       : S2`
>
> `ServiceObjectiveAssignmentStateDescription : Complete`
>
> `CreationDate                               : 11-Mar-15 11:07:30 AM`
>
> `RecoveryPeriodStartDate                    : 11-Mar-15 11:37:31 AM`

---

From this file I need to create a file with Name and creation date only. so the output file should be like as follows :

> `abc                02-Jul-14 4:14:19 AM`
>
> `def                25-Jan-15 6:39:41 PM`
>
> `ghi                25-Jan-15 3:19:01 PM`
>
> `hjiyt              11-Mar-15 11:07:30 AM`

It would be great if anyone help me to do this using powershell.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a script sample that doens't work because of a specific problem? This isn't Amazon for code, we're here to help you with specific problems, not write the code for you. :-)  Keywords for solution: `Get-Content`, `about_split`, `Foreach-Object`, `regex`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have at least PowerShell 3.0 ( For the `-Raw` switch of `Get-Content`. If you don't an easy change can account for that) we can convert that text file into a PowerShell object which would make data manipulation easy.

```powershell
$fileDataObject = (Get-Content C:\temp\data.log -Raw) -split "\b(?=Name\s+:)" | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object{
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property ($_ -replace "\s:\s","=" | ConvertFrom-StringData)
}

$fileDataObject | ForEach-Object{"{0,-20}{1,-25}" -f $_.Name,$_.CreationDate} | Set-Content "C:\temp\output.txt"
```

Take the raw data from "C:\temp\data.log" and split the file into chunks where the lines are `Name   : text`. That would return five groups, first one being empty, and we skip the first one.

Those chunks of data are asking to be converted to hash tables using `key=value` data pairs. We then convert all the colons that are in between white-space into equal signs so satisfy the needs of `ConvertFrom-StringData`. This transformation is captured into `$fileDataObject`. You can see its contents below which have been formatted for this answer.

```powershell
Name  CollationName    Edition  MaxSizeGB MaxSizeBytes ServiceObjectiveName ServiceObjectiveAssignmentStateDescription CreationDate          RecoveryPeriodStartDate
----  -------------    -------  --------- ------------ -------------------- ------------------------------------------ ------------          -----------------------
abc   xxxxxxxxx        System   5         5368709120   System               Complete                                   02-Jul-14 4:14:19 AM  02-Jul-14 4:14:19 AM   
def   xxxxxxxxxxxxx    Standard 250       268435456000 S2                   Complete                                   25-Jan-15 6:39:41 PM  01-Mar-15 3:00:00 AM   
ghi   xxxxxxxx         Standard 250       268435456000 S2                   Complete                                   25-Jan-15 3:19:01 PM  01-Mar-15 3:00:00 AM   
hjiyt xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Standard 250       268435456000 S2                   Complete                                   11-Mar-15 11:07:30 AM 11-Mar-15 11:37:31 AM
```

Since you just want those 2 columns of data in the output we can arrange that using the format parameter. I saw in the OP that you have 20 character spacing for the Name so that was enforced for the output as well using the `-f` operator.

Assuming no preexisting data in "C:\temp\output.txt" you should see the output you desire.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sourcePath = "C:\test.txt"
$targetPath = "C:\output.txt"

$output = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder

Get-Content $sourcePath | 
    Where-Object { $_.ToString().StartsWith("Name") -or $_.ToString().StartsWith("CreationDate") } | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        $value = $_.ToString().Split(@(':'), 2, [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)[1].Trim()
        $temp = New-Object System.DateTime
        $isDateTime = [DateTime]::TryParse($value, [ref]$temp)
        if ($isDateTime) {      
            $output.AppendLine("`t`t`t`t`t$value")
        }
        else {
            $output.Append($value)
        }
    }

Set-Content $targetPath $output.ToString().Trim()
```

You can improve this where required, but with your sample data shown here it should work.